# Passing Colon in curl function issue

Tags: php, curl

I have this function:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $ua = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua); 


    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

Now I have a strange issue: I;m trying to search in Google
using the "inurl:example.com", like this:

```
$email =  $_GET["email"];
$in = "inurl:example.com+" . $email;
$in = str_replace(' ','+',$in);
$url  = 'http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q='.$in;
```

and every time i get 0 results.

However, when i get rid from the "inurl:" and replace it with some other
condition, like this:

```
$in = "example.com+" . $email;
```

it works well and i see the results.

So something about the COLON ("inurl:") causes trouble for the file_get_contents_curl function.

I tried the same inurl: string in file_get_html function (instead of file_get_contents_curl)

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
```

with no problem at all.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

```
$in = "+inurl:pastebin.com";
$in = str_replace("%3A",":",$in);
```

(NOT) solved the problem.

**EDIT:**
Sometimes it works and sometimes not.
So it's something related to Google blocking/rate-limit
and stuff like that.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you try urlencoding that ?

Comment: In your example, `"+inurl:pastebin.com"` does not contain the string literal `"%3A"`, so `$in = str_replace("%3A",":",$in);` will not have any effect. I can't see how it could have solved your problem.